# C: SEGFAULT with 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to copy 3 strings from 2D const char array into a double pointer of char.

```
char **E = malloc(sizeof(char));
const char *e[3] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
  for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
    {
      E[k] = malloc(sizeof(char));
      strcpy(E[k], e[k]); //crash occurs here
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is when you want E to point to the same constant strings
as the variable e.

Try this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int
 main(void)
 {
    char **E = malloc(3*sizeof(char *));
    const char *e[3] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
    int k;

    for (k=0; k<3; k++)
    {  
       E[k] = e[k];      
    }
    for( k=0; k<3; k++ )
    {
       printf( "%s\n", E[k]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the explanation.

The variable 'e' is an array of 3 pointers to constant characters.

Lets say "aa" is stored in memory address of 100.

Lets say "bb" is stored in memory address of 200.

Lets say "cc" is stored in memory address of 300.

The 'e' variable looks like this:

e[0]   e[1]    e[2]

|------|-------|------|

|  100 | 200   | 300  |

|------|-------|------|

The E[k] = e[k]; assignment would result E to look like

E[0]   E[1]    E[2]

|------|-------|------|

|  100 | 200   | 300  |

|------|-------|------|

Answer (score 1):

```
char **E = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

A pointer to pointer to `char` must reserve space for a pointer to `char`, not for a plain `char`.

It seems that you want a modifiable copy of the constant array of pointers, then change to:

```
char **E = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
const char *e[3] = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
{
     E[k] = malloc(strlen(e[k]) + 1);
     strcpy(E[k], e[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char **E = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
char **E = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
```

The former allocates just *one* byte but you need to allocate memory for 3 pointers to `char` (`char*`) and this is what the latter does.

Similarly,

```
E[k] = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
E[k] = malloc(strlen(e[k]) + 1);
```

as you need memory to store each of the respective strings (+1 for the NUL-terminator `'\0'`) in `E[K]` and not just 1 byte.

Comment: On a pedantic note, this isn't technically a 2D array; arrays are described in C as contiguous, single-allocation blocks of elements with no padding between.

Answer (score 0):

E is a `char**`, which means that it contains `char*` that themselves contain `char`.
This mean that E have to be allocated enough space to contain the `char*`, that mean malloc of:

`sizeof(char*) * thenumberofchar*youwantittocontains`

Same goes for each `char*` (`E[k]`) contained into E, they have to be allocated of

```
sizeof(char) * thenumberofcharyouwanittocontains + 1 (for the '/0' character that tell that the char* has ended)
```

Because if you don't allocate enough memory space, you won't be able to write at all memory location you're trying to access via `E[k]` and even `E[k][i]`, because it's not allocated for your program, causing a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why all that size is needed - AFAIK, a char* needs only sizeof(char) for the allocation.

Comment: You're sadly wrong. Let met edit my post to explain it :)

Comment: Ok, but `char *p = malloc(sizeof(char))` works for me without any problem.

Comment: @user6039980 by doing so, you're saying that p will contain only one char (one character)

Comment: the code `const char *s = "hello; strcpy(p,s); printf("%s", p);` works without any problem. Also the code I published above works with no problem, The code I posted is just a rewrite of my original one, the problem is caused by another bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141259/discussion-between-sorikairo-and-user6039980).